# How to compute the satellite footprint latitude and longitude for different countour?

Tags: communication-satellite, satellite-constellation

Given a satellite coordinates, the antenna gain pattern of the satellite (example a dish antenna at given frequency and with known diameter), the off-nadir angle and the satellite slant range i need to understand how to compute the latitude and longitude for each point of a given specified countour (example -3dB countour).

Comment: This problem has two parts. 1) Set up the geometry properly so that for a given lat/lon one can calculate the point in the antenna gain pattern and $1/r^2$ to get the power at the Earth's surface, and 2) Generate contours. I think that the $1/r^2$ is your "satellite slant range" but if the satellite is in LEO it will be different for each lat/lon point, and the "off-nadir angle" is really two angles, because it has a direction as well as a magnitude; it could be pointing north, south, east, or west of nadir or anywhere in between.

Comment: Can you include some specific example data showing exactly what inputs you have to work with, that will make it easier for answers to address your scenario in the most helpful way. Thanks, and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*